# selectedSegmentIndex always be -1

Tags: objective-c, ios, uisegmentedcontrol

I made a custom `UISegmentedControl`, I add subview button on init and add target for every button them set `selectedSegmentIndex` in every target actions. but when I `NSLog` after set value. I found they always be -1. Does anyone knows about this. Pls help.

here is the code in action function:

```
[self setSelectedSegmentIndex:tabID];
[self sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
NSLog(@"selected: %d", self.selectedSegmentIndex);
```

Comment: Add a breakpoint and check with `po self.selectedSegmentIndex`. I'm not sure you're allowed to use `%d` to show it. Maybe `%i`? selectedSegmentIndex is NSInteger.

Comment: tabID is the tag for the clicked button, I set tag for every button.

Comment: I'm think just need to custom an UIView and add some buttons to made my float bar, segmentedControl seems to many properities I do not need to use.